# Trying to overlay geotiff file on OL map and its showing error

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3, tiff, geotiff

I need to overlay tiff image on **Openlayer map**,i get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: This reference system is not handled : use proj4js
>   in conjunction to OL3 and GeotiffParser 32767
>       at GeoCanvas.parseTif

there are few other tiff which is working fine also.

reference link (i got idea from this and implemented it) - https://yugniro.github.io/geotiff-canvas/example.html

please do suggest a solution.

Comment: It's nice that you provided the example you followed, but the problem is with your code, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

You can find that message in the non-minified code here https://github.com/yugniro/geotiff-canvas/tree/master/dist/js

If an OpenLayers map uses a projection other than EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326 it needs to include proj4js, That would also apply if a GeoTiff specified such a projection. So you would need to include the proj4js library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.0/proj4.js"></script>
```

and would also need to define the EPSG:32767 projection the GeoTiff is using. Unfortunately the EPSG:32767 code is used for user defined projections so you may not be able to get the definition you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i added proj4js in my script, still getting the error. isn't there any other way to get it working? like transforming the user defined projection to any other